# Numpy Concatenate to empty array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to concatenate a set of numpy arrays loaded from disk. All arrays have varying number of columns.

This is my code

```
import numpy as np

FILE_LIST = ["matrix a", "matrix b"]

result=np.array([[0,0],[0,0]]) # I need to avoid this zero matrix
for fileName in FILE_LIST:
    matrix = matrix= np.genfromtxt(fileName, delimiter=" ")    
    result = np.concatenate((result, matrix),axis=1) 

print result
```

Here I have initialised result to an array with zeroes as I cannot concatenate to an empty array. I need to avoid this zero array appended at the beginning of the result. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to first load all the data in an array and then apply numpys `hstack` in order to horizontally stack the arrays

```
result = np.hstack([np.genfromtxt(fileName,delimiter=" ") for fileName in FILE_LIST])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious why you need to avoid this.  But you could do:

```
result=None
for fileName in FILE_LIST:
    matrix= np.genfromtxt(fileName, delimiter=" ")
    if result is None:
        result = matrix
    else:
        result = np.concatenate((result, matrix),axis=1)
```

Generally we try to avoid repeated concatenation (or append) to arrays, prefering instead to append to lists.  But in this case `genfromtxt` is a big enough operation that it doesn't matter much how you combine the arrays.

With a list, the loop would be:

```
result=[]
for fileName in FILE_LIST:
    result.append(np.genfromtxt(fileName, delimiter=" "))    
result = np.concatenate(result,axis=1)
```

A list comprehension is essentially the same thing.